# matplotlib lib for multiple lines is giving strange result in y axis data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to represent multiple lines in matplotlib plot and i am getting some strange results and can see multiple y-axis range.
my values will be in range [0.0, 15.0].

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

def image_graph():
    left_image_data = ['10.31', '10.21', '10.13', '10.08', '10.1']
    right_image_data = ['10.17', '10.14', '10.13', '10.1', '10.07']
    near_proximity_image_data = ['9.257', '9.601', '9.688', '9.76', '9.824']
    far_proximity_image_data = ['9.999', '9.997', '10.0', '10.0', '9.996']
    image_data_x = [datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 19, 21, 30, 20, 876981), datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 19, 21, 30, 20, 877015), datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 19, 21, 30, 20, 877031), datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 19, 21, 30, 20, 877046), datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 19, 21, 30, 20, 877057)]


    plt.plot(image_data_x, left_image_data, label="left_image_data time rate")
    plt.plot(image_data_x, right_image_data, label="right_image_data time rate")
    plt.plot(image_data_x, near_proximity_image_data, label="near_proximity_image")
    plt.plot(image_data_x, far_proximity_image_data, label="far_proximity_image")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


image_graph()
```

Can someone help me in solving this `left_image_data` and `right_image_data` values are represented in correct way but other 2 values behaves strange when you see the values of y-axis is again starts instead of showing in same area.

[image: plot image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` is currently a `str` type. It should be converted to a numeric type (such as `float`) before plotting.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np

def image_graph():
    left_image_data = ['10.31', '10.21', '10.13', '10.08', '10.1']
    right_image_data = ['10.17', '10.14', '10.13', '10.1', '10.07']
    near_proximity_image_data = ['9.257', '9.601', '9.688', '9.76', '9.824']
    far_proximity_image_data = ['9.999', '9.997', '10.0', '10.0', '9.996']
    image_data_x = [datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 19, 21, 30, 20, 876981), datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 19, 21, 30, 20, 877015), datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 19, 21, 30, 20, 877031), datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 19, 21, 30, 20, 877046), datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 19, 21, 30, 20, 877057)]


    plt.plot(image_data_x, [float(num) for num in left_image_data], label="left_image_data time rate")
    plt.plot(image_data_x, [float(num) for num in right_image_data], label="right_image_data time rate")
    plt.plot(image_data_x, [float(num) for num in near_proximity_image_data], label="near_proximity_image")
    plt.plot(image_data_x, [float(num) for num in far_proximity_image_data], label="far_proximity_image")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


image_graph()
```

If you're going to do a lot of such conversion, `numpy` is useful. I've just used standard `python` in this example in keeping with your example.